# resizing UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipickerview

I'm trying to create an UIPickerView in UIAlertView, I wrote the following code

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];

alert.title = @"Preferences";
alert.message = @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
alert.delegate = self;
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];


UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
myPickerView.autoresizingMask = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;

myPickerView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 250, 150);

[alert addSubview:myPickerView];

[alert show];
```

but when run, the pickerView size is not fit the alert view, it looks as shown in the image.

[here image](http://dt-works.com/emy/Screen%20Shot%202012-07-31%20at%2010.44.12%20AM.png)

how can I solve this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

---

I solved it, I discovered that I have the following code

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component    {
int sectionWidth = 300;

return sectionWidth;
}
```

when I removed this, It fixed. :)
thanks for everyone tried to help me, and I'm very sorry for my mistake. :$

Comment: you can change width of picker view

Comment: I tried to decrease it, but it decreases the line "the edge of the picker " in the right side, and the remaining of the picker passes the edge of the alert

Answer (score 1):

I had a requirement similar to this. But I couldn't succeed it using 'UIPickerView'. So I moved to 'AFPickerView'. May be that would help you too!!

Answer (score 0):

You can not resize pickerView height only change width and x and y coordinates 
Or you have to make alertview big eno

Comment: yes, I'm trying to change the width only to not pass the edges of the alertView, I tried to make the alertView width bigger but it still passes the edges as shown in the image :S

Comment: It can possible to resize it.

Comment: how ?? is there are any mistakes in my code ?? or can you suggest a sample code for me ??

Comment: you should disable autoresize subviews of alertview ... i think this is the problem make autoresizesubview of alert view  = false

Answer (score 0):

I'm seriously questioning this style. Besides, I dont think you can actually change the size of an UIAlertView. I suggest you perform a modal segue with form sheet presentation to show a UIView wich you placed an UIPickerview on with some buttons to confirm or cancel. You can do this using a StoryBoard or program it manually.

Comment: but the requirements of my project tells me to perform this style :S its important to add a pickerView in the alerView :S

Comment: The documentation says: "The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified." Meaning that the UIAlertView will adapt itself in size for your message to fit, but you can not force it to be a certain size nor should the view hierarchy be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Width in xib.For this you need to open the Xib in XML form and find that PickerView  and change the width and save,run.Hope This Will Work!!